# Django CSRF cookie not set when sending JSON

Tags: django, json, cookies, csrf, django-csrf

I guess this question is very lame, but I actually tried everything before posting. All the questions alike on SO are not answered.

My code goes like:

```
@csrf_protect
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(
                   {'username':request.user.username}
               ), mimetype='application/json')
```

Django needs to add a `Set-Cookie` header to the response when serving this view, but it doesn't. The `csrftoken` cookie is not there after I get a response from this view, and it's not in the headers. `CSRFMiddleware` is on and works for other parts of the site. How do I get Django to set the cookie?

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does not set the cookie value to response headers when it return json data,so you need to set cookie value in response object manually.  code like this:

```
@csrf_protect
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        response =  HttpResponse(json.dumps(
                   {'username':request.user.username}
               ), mimetype='application/json')

        response.set_cookie('hello','world')
        return response
```

Comment: why didn't you approve my edit? it shows the answer to the `csrf` question I was asking - the information not contained in this answer

Comment: @martinthenext 
Rejected yesterday:
CuberChase reviewed this yesterday: Reject
This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.
michaelb958 reviewed this yesterday: Reject
This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.
dmahapatro reviewed this yesterday: Approve
Java Devil reviewed this yesterday: Reject
This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.